# Is it possible for an entry to have two URL in Expression Engine, and translate template names?

Tags: multilingual, expressionengine

I'm currently making a bilingual Expression Engine 2.5.2 website. I'm using [this technique](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site_alternative/#Slight_modification_for_EE2) to create the two langues, which works perfectly.

I have created a {country_code} global variable in the two index.php files which allows me to detect the current language.

Using this technique, I have no problems to get language-relative data when accessing an entry. My only concern is that I apparently have to privilege a language-specific "clean" URL.

**Example entry:**

- {entry_id} = 123
- {title} = My test article
- {title_permalink} = my-test-article
- {name_fr} = Mon article
- {name_en} = My article

If I request `http://www.example.com/index.php/en/blog/articles/my-test-article`, I expect to to find, in english, "My article" using the template articles in the blog template group.

Everything is fine, but the french translation is accessible when requesting `http://www.example.com/index.php/fr/blog/articles/my-test-article`. The correct translation of the URL should be `http://www.example.com/index.php/fr/blogue/articles/mon-article-test`.

Anyone encountered a problem like this? Any solutions via extensions or modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [Transcribe module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/transcribe) solves this by both providing the ability to translate template group and template names, and having you create a separate entry for each language and piece of content in your site (hence, you have two separate URL titles). But that means buying into their entire methodology for a multi-lingual site.

Myself, I usually just stick to using the `entry_id` instead of the `url_title`, and live with the template names being in the primary language.

Comment: Yes, I found out about Transcribe, which seems to be everything I need right now. Like you said, it means you buy into their methodology, and mixed with a 150$ price tag, I'd like to explore other options. Entry ID would work, but the goal here is preserving "clean, beautiful" URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to achieve this is by embedding templates with segment translations, duplicating template groups and duplicating channels.

In the `blog/articles` template:

`{embed="shared/.head" segment_2_translation="blogue" segment_3_translation="articles"}`

In the `blogue/articles` template:

`{embed="shared/.head" segment_2_translation="blog" segment_3_translation="articles"}`

In `shared/.head` template:

`[...] <a href="/{lang}/{if embed:segment_2_translated}{segment_2_translated}/{/if}{if embed:segment_3_translated}{segment_3_translated}/{/if}">{if lang == "fr"}English{if:else}Français{/if}</a> [...]`

And then you can create a `Articles (FR)` and a `Articles (EN)` channels, and each will have their unique URL titles. You can also add a relationship custom field for each channel to associate an entry with it's translation.

It feels messy, but it is the only way I could make it work without modules, plugins or whatnot.